# biblatex-dw disable idem for no author

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-dw

I'm using the `footnote-dw` citation style from the package `biblatex-dw`. In my thesis I am working with a lot of newspaper articles where no author information is given. Currently I am using 'o. A.' (German abbreviation for 'without author') as author information in my bibtex file. In my bibliography the author field gets replaced by the German idem 'Ders.' which means 'the same', which is wrong because the authors are not the same.

Is it possible to deactivate the idem feature of `biblatex-dw` for entries that have 'o. A.' as author field?

The issue happens with the following example document and bibtex file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{Test Dokument}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Das ist ein Testdokument.\cite{test1} Das ist ein zweiter Test.\cite{test2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

```
@article{test1,
  author          = {o.~A.},
  journal         = {Test Zeitung},
  title           = {Test Artikel 1},
  year            = {2023}
}

@article{test2,
  author          = {o.~A.},
  journal         = {Test Zeitung 2},
  title           = {Test Artikel 2},
  year            = {2023}
}
```

In the second article (test2) the author field is replaced with "Ders." in the output document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While your question can be understood without one, it is a very nice gesture to post an example document that reproduces what you are asking about with as little excess code as possible. That way those trying to help you can get started quickly, test their solution with your setup and we can all be sure we're talking about the same thing. So please consider adding a small example document that shows the status quo in your document.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your reply! I added an example that reproduces the described behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-dw` has several options and settings to stop "idem" from appearing, but I couldn't find a one-stop solution, so here is an attempt at writing a per-entry option to suppress "idem" for this specific entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=footnote-dw,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareEntryOption{noidem}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\boolfalse{bbx:idembib}%
     \booltrue{cbx:noidem}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author  = {o.~A.},
  journal = {Test Zeitung},
  title   = {Test Artikel 1},
  year    = {2023},
  options = {noidem},
}
@article{test2,
  author  = {o.~A.},
  journal = {Test Zeitung 2},
  title   = {Test Artikel 2},
  year    = {2023},
  options = {noidem},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Das ist ein Testdokument.\cite{test1}
Das ist ein zweiter Test.\cite{test2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: o. A.: Test Artikel 1, in: Test Zeitung 2023. o. A.: Test Artikel 2, in: Test Zeitung 2 2023.]